# how to get VTTimeZone in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, icalendar

I am working with iCalendar, in my app user can able to create Calendar,EKEvents... when i tried to export my ical, lot of datas missing.

i am using this sample for exporting my iCal file

```
  "https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/EKEventToiCal" 


BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Kolkata
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0630
DTSTART:19420515T000000
TZNAME:IST
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
RDATE:19420515T000000
RDATE:19451015T000000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
DTSTART:19420901T000000
TZNAME:GMT+05:30
TZOFFSETTO:+0630
RDATE:19420901T000000
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

i miss these details from my events, please anyone worked on these icalendar and ekevent. if you worked or known about icalendar export timezone. Please give me reference link or sample code.

Comment: Any chance you figured this out @banu?

Comment: @banu I stumbled across this recently:the formatting  done by EKEventToICal hardcodes 

        DTSTART;TZID=America/Denver:

if you simply replace “America/Denver” with the actual timeZone name of your EKEvent this works in most ical clients (Google,Apple calendar) without the need  to actually specify/implement the VTIMEZONE lines. This may be non standard, but is simple to achieve.